# SQL query retrieve fields from current date

Tags: php, sql

This is my database SQL code;

```
CREATE TABLE ProductType
(
    ptID int not null auto_increment,
    pType varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(ptID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Service
(
    sID int not null auto_increment,
    description varchar(30) not null,
    revenue int,
    stID int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(sID),
    FOREIGN KEY(stID) references ServiceType(stID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Product
(
    pID int not null auto_increment,
    model varchar(30) not null,
    cogs int,
    ptID int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(pID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ptID) references ProductType(ptID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Sale
(
    saleID int not null auto_increment,
    assetID int not null,
    eID int not null,
    sID int not null,
    pID int,  
    saDate date not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(saleID),
    FOREIGN KEY(eID) references Employee(eID),
    FOREIGN KEY(sID) references Service(sID),
    FOREIGN KEY(pID) references Product(pID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    eID int not null auto_increment,
    firstName varchar(30) not null,
    lastName varchar(30) not null,
    phone varchar(30),
    email varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(eID)
)
```

This is my attempt but I don't know how to access the 'revenue' field from 'Service' when I am querying the 'Sale' table.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pnl") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sale WHERE saDate = CURDATE()")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

echo "revenue: ".$row['revenue'];

?>
```

Can anyone give me an example of how I would write a php script to retrieve the revenue of  all sales for the current date?

Also this was my first attempt at SQL and relational database models, so if you notice any critical mistakes I've made or things I can improve please let me know!

Comment: Which column references price in your `Sale` table?

Comment: Attempt is in the edit. @David I thought I could access revenue from Service through the FK Service(sID). Am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: Try this. I'm not sure if I understand how your data works, yet. `SELECT SUM(Service.revenue) FROM Service JOIN Sale ON Sale.sID = Service.sID WHERE Sale.saDate = 'YOUR DATE FORMAT'`

Comment: @David This did not work, or perhaps I am not outputting the result properly. `echo "revenue: ".$row['field'];` What field would I be using here? 'revenue'?

Comment: I forgot to put `AS`. Try this: `SELECT SUM(Service.revenue) AS revenue_total FROM Service JOIN Sale ON Sale.sID = Service.sID WHERE Sale.saDate = 'YOUR DATE FORMAT'` Then `echo $row['revenue_total']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. Name the SUM field and access it by given name:

```
// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Service.revenue) sum FROM Service JOIN Sale ON Sale.sID = Service.sID WHERE Sale.saDate = $some_date") or die(mysql_error());  
// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 
echo "revenue: ".$row['sum'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If sID on sales and Service both are same and unique to every sales then you can use query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT Sale.saleID, Sale.assetID, Sale.eID, Sale.sID, Sale.pID, Sale.saDate, Service.revenue "."FROM Sale, Service "."WHERE Sale.sID = Service.sID AND Sale.saDate = CURDATE()) or die(mysql_error());
```

Or if `Service.sID = Sale.saleID` then change acordingly.

This way you can control which column exactly you would like to retrive from each table.

Comment: sID != saleID, Service is more of a profile for what the Sale includes (e.g. mobile $40 plan) along with a product (e.g. iPhone) and employee who made the sale (e.g. Tom). What I want to do here is display the total revenue from all sales from the current day. Like a real-time display of a businesses revenue. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: If sId != saleID then I will recomend to include saleID on Service table also and change the where clause to : WHERE Sale.saleID = Service.saleID AND Sale.saDate = CURDATE() and I hope this will solve your issue.